# how to Check Model Data Exists In another Table

Tags: sql, laravel

i'm trying to get All RequestStates Where DepartMent_id 's equals with  my department_id
But before returning the result, it should be checked that the User_Id field  doesn't exists
in Graduate Table

this is my code :

```
$request=RequestState::where('department_id',auth()->user()->department_id)->get();
```

Relations:

**Request** HasMany **Request_State**

**User** Has One **Graduate**

Tables :

**Reqeuest_STATE TABLE** :

[image: request state table]

**USER TABLE**

[image: user table]

**Request Table:**

[image]

**Graduate Table**

[image]

Comment: instead of wherehas you can use whereExists

Comment: User::with('request','request.requestState')->whereHas('request.requestState',function($query){
        $query->where('department_id',auth()->user()->department_id) ;
    })->find(auth()->user()->id);

Comment: @JohnLobo Graduate Table Doesn't Check ???

Comment: User::with('request','request.requestState')->whereHas('request.requestState',function($query){
$query->where('department_id',auth()->user()->department_id)
})->whereHas('graduate')->find(auth()->user()->id);;